# How to assign string PHP variable (function) in smarty?

Tags: smarty, assign

I need to change **from section** by **$type**. In from section we have an PHP static functions:

```
{foreach from=dbPay::getAll(null) item=dbPay}
{foreach from=dbPay::getSomething(null) item=dbPay}
etc.
```

Let's see, we make an variable for that:

```
{foreach from={$static_php_function} item=dbPay}
```

Usage:

```
{if ($type == 1)}
  // need to assign: dbPay::getAll(null)
  // ?? {assign var="static_php_function" value="dbPay::getAll(null)"}
{elseif ($type == 2)}
  // need to assign: dbPay::getSomething(null)
  // ?? {assign var="static_php_function" value="dbPay::getSomething(null)"}
{/if}


{foreach from={$static_php_function} item=dbPay}
...
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drop double quotes around function call, and curly braces around variable name in foreach loop:

```
{if ($type == 1)}
    {assign var="static_php_function_result" value=dbPay::getAll(null)}
{elseif ($type == 2)}
    {assign var="static_php_function_result" value=dbPay::getSomething(null)}
{/if}


{foreach from=$static_php_function_result item=dbPay}
...
{/foreach}
```

Remember that it does not assign function for later call, but result to operate on.

Answer (score -2):

simple
add the output of you function depending what type it is in the handler to a var.
add that var to you template.
And fixed.